# How to interpret unicode encodings

Tags: character-encoding

I just finished reading the article ["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) by Joel Spolsky.

I'd really appreciate clarification on this part of the article.

> OK, so say we have a string: Hello which, in Unicode, corresponds to these five code points:
>    U+0048 U+0065 U+006C U+006C U+006F...That’s where encodings come in.
>
> The earliest idea for Unicode encoding, which led to the myth about the two bytes, was, hey, let’s just store those numbers in two bytes each. So Hello becomes
>
> 00 48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F
>
> Right? Not so fast! Couldn’t it also be:
>
> 48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00 ?
>
> Well, technically, yes, I do believe it could, and, in fact, early implementors wanted to be able to store their Unicode code points in high-endian or low-endian mode, whichever their particular CPU was fastest at, and lo, it was evening and it was morning and there were already two ways to store Unicode. So the people were forced to come up with the bizarre convention of storing a FE FF at the beginning of every Unicode string; this is called a Unicode Byte Order Mark and if you are swapping your high and low bytes it will look like a FF FE and the person reading your string will know that they have to swap every other byte. Phew. Not every Unicode string in the wild has a byte order mark at the beginning.

My questions:

Why could the two zero's at the beginning of 0048 be moved to the end?

What is FE FF and FF FE, what's the difference between them and how were they used? (Yes I tried googling those terms, but I'm still confused)

Why did he then say "Phew. Not every Unicode string in the wild has a byte order mark at the beginning."?

Also, I'd appreciate any recommended resources to learn more about this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary:** the `0xFEFF` (byte-order mark) character is used to solve the endianness problem for some character encodings. However, most of today's character encodings are not prone to the endianness problem, and thus the byte-order mark is not really relevant for today.

---

> Why could the two zero's at the beginning of 0048 be moved to the end?

If two bytes are used for all characters, then each character is saved in a 2-byte data structure in the memory of the computer. Bytes (groups of 8 bits) are the basic addressable units in most computer memories, and each byte has its own address. On systems that use the **big-endian** format, the character `0x0048` would be saved in two 1-byte memory cells in the following way:

```
 n    n+1
+----+----+
| 00 | 48 |
+----+----+
```

Here, `n` and `n+1` are the addresses of the memory cells. Thus, on big-endian systems, the **most significant** byte is stored in the **lowest** memory address of the data structure.

On a **little-endian** system, on the other hand, the character `0x0048`would be stored in the following way:

```
 n    n+1
+----+----+
| 48 | 00 |
+----+----+
```

Thus, on little-endian systems, the **least significant** byte is stored in the **lowest** memory address of the data structure.

So, if a big-endian system sends you the character `0x0048` (for example, over the network), it sends you the byte sequence `00` `48`. On the other hand, if a little-endian system sends you the character `0x0048`, it sends you the byte sequence `48` `00`.

So, if you receive a byte sequence like `00` `48`, and you know that it represents a 16-bit character, you need to know whether the sender was a big-endian or little-endian system. In the first case, `00` `48` would mean the character `0x0048`, in the second case, `00` `48` would mean the totally different character `0x4800`.

This is where the `FE` `FF` sequence comes in.

> What is FE FF and FF FE, what's the difference between them and how were they used?

`U+FEFF` is the Unicode [byte-order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), and in our example of a 2-byte encoding, this would be the 16-bit character `0xFEFF`.

The convention is that all systems (big-endian and little-endian) save the character `0xFEFF` as the first character of any text stream. Now, on a big-endian system, this character is represented as the byte sequence `FE` `FF` (assume memory addresses increasing from left to right), whereas on a little-endian system, it is represented as `FF` `FE`.

Now, if you read a text stream, that has been created by following this convention, you know that the first character must be `0xFEFF`. So, if the first two bytes of the text stream are `FE` `FF`, you know that this text stream has been created by a **big-endian** system. On the other hand, if the first two bytes are `FF` `FE`, you know that the text stream has been created by a **little-endian** system. In either case, you can now correctly interpret all the 2-byte characters of the stream.

> Why did he then say "Phew. Not every Unicode string in the wild has a byte order mark at the beginning."?

Placing the byte-order mark (BOM) character `0xFEFF` at the beginning of each text stream is just a convention, and not all systems may follow it. So, if the BOM is  missing, you have the problem of not knowing whether to interpret the 2-byte characters as big-endian or little-endian.

> Also, I'd appreciate any recommended resources to learn more about this stuff.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes

---

**Notes:**

Today, the most widely used Unicode-compatible encoding is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). UTF-8 has been designed to avoid the endianness problem, thus, the entire byte-order mark `0xFEFF` stuff is **not relevant for UTF-8** (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)).

The byte-order mark is however relevant to the other Unicode-compatible encodings [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) and [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32), which are prone to the endianness problem. If you browse through the list of available encodings, for example in the settings of a text editor or terminal, you see that there are big-endian and little-endian versions of UTF-16 and UTF-32, typically called UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE, or UTF-32BE and UTF-32LE, respectively. However, **UTF-16 and UTF-32 are rarely used in practice**.

Other popular encodings used today include the encodings from the [ISO 8859 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859), such as [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (and the derived [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)), known as Latin-1, or also the pure [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding. However, all these are **single-byte encodings**, that is, each character is encoded to 1 byte and saved in a 1-byte data structure. Thus, the endianness problem doesn't apply here, and the byte-order mark story is also **not relevant for these cases**.

All in all, the endianness problem for character encodings, that you struggled to understand, has thus mostly a historical value, and is **not really relevant for today's world anymore**.

Comment: This was really helpful. I'm now almost certain that I made the mistake of reading the two versions of interpreting hello incorrectly. Initially I thought that only the first two zero's in 00 48 were moved to the end, while in reality the high endian version was the first example and if one were to translate from high endian to low endian you'd have to swap the 48 and the first pair of 00's then swap the 65 and the 2nd pair of 00's etc. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think you interpreted it like only moving the first byte `00` of the stream to the very end of the stream? No. For transforming from big-endian to little-endian, you change the position of *all pairs of bytes*. So, `00 48` becomes `48 00`, and `00 65` becomes `65 00`, and so on, as you correctly described it. And yes, the first string in the article is big-endian, the second is little-endian.

Answer (score 1):

This is all to do with the internal storage of data in the computer's memory - in this example (00 48), some computers will store the largest byte first and the smallest byte second (known as big-endian), and others will store the smallest byte first (little-endian). So, depending on your computer, when you read the bytes out of memory you'll get either the 00 first or the 48 first. And you need to know which way round it's going to be to make sure you interpret the bytes correctly. For a more in-depth introduction to the topic, see Endianness on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

These days, most compilers and interpreters will take care of this low-level stuff for you, so you will rarely (if ever) need to worry about it.